# Default Value On A Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, contact, default-value

I created a custom percent field on the contact record page and entered in a default value in the "general options" section, but the default value will not auto-populate when I go to the contact record page. I just want the number to appear as 100. Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm what value did  you give as default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new field and populate the default value as some value.The existing record won't get the default values. It will be null for existing records. Please find the below [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdl88UAB/new-field-creation-option-to-update-the-existing-records-with-default-values) for the same where you can upvote for the same.